Having trouble downloading and unzipping image file in React Native Expo app
This function downloads a zip file and unzips it and saves the unzipped image files into the expo file system of the React Native Expo app. It does successfully download the file, unzip and save the images. The problem is that when I display the images, they appear corrupted and distorted. I suspect there is something wrong with this function causing this issue and I would appreciate any advice.
const readZipFile = async (uri: string, privateAssetsDirectory: string) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(uri, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
        const zipBuffer = response.data;

        // Create a new JSZip instance and load the zip buffer
        const zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(zipBuffer);

        // Get an array of file keys
        const fileKeys = Object.keys(zip.files);

        // Iterate over each file key in the zip archive
        for (const filename of fileKeys) {
            const file = zip.files[filename];
            if (!file.dir && !isSystemFile(filename)) { // Exclude directories
                // Extract the file contents as Uint8Array
                const content = await file.async('uint8array');

                // Convert Uint8Array to Base64 string
                let base64Content = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i += 1024) {
                    const chunk = content.subarray(i, i + 1024);
                    base64Content += btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, chunk));
                }

                // Save the file to the directory where the zip file is located
                const filePath = privateAssetsDirectory + filename;

                await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
                    filePath,
                    base64Content,
                    { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 }
                );

                //console.log('File:', filename, ', Size:', content.length);
                //console.log('Saved at:', filePath);
            }
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading zip file:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

I expected the images to display but they are distorted. You can only see part of what the images is supposed to contain and part of the images are just grey.

I got this working like this using react native and expo. With this function I downloaded and unpacked multiple images. Then I displayed them with <Image> and they were not corrupted or distorted, basically everything worked fine. Hope it helps!
I used fflate instead of jszip, have not tried jszip although I've tried react-native-zip-archive and it did not even build for me.
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import { unzipSync } from "fflate";
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

const downloadAndUzipFiles = async (
  url: string,
  targetZipFilePath: string,
  targetUnzipPath: string
): Promise<string[]> => {
  console.log("Downloading from", url);
  const downloadResult = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(url, targetZipFilePath);
  console.log("Downloaded to", downloadResult.uri);
  const zipFileBase64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(downloadResult.uri, {
    encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
  });

  // Convert base64 string to Uint8Array for fflate to process
  const zipArray = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(zipFileBase64, "base64"));

  // Unzip the file using fflate
  const unzippedFiles = unzipSync(zipArray); // unzippedFiles is an object with file names as keys and Uint8Array as values
  console.log("Files unzipped:", Object.keys(unzippedFiles));

  // Ensure the unzipped folder exists
  const folderInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(targetUnzipPath);
  if (!folderInfo.exists) {
    console.log("directory does not exist, creating...", targetUnzipPath);
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(targetUnzipPath, {
      intermediates: true,
    });
  } else {
    console.log("directory exists, resetting...", targetUnzipPath);
    await FileSystem.deleteAsync(targetUnzipPath, { idempotent: true });
    await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(targetUnzipPath, {
      intermediates: true,
    });
  }

  // Save each unzipped file to the unzipped folder
  const savedFiles = [];
  for (const [fileName, fileData] of Object.entries(unzippedFiles)) {
    const filePath = targetUnzipPath + fileName;

    const base64Content = Buffer.from(fileData).toString("base64");

    // Convert the file content (Uint8Array) to string (for text files) or directly save binary data (for images, etc.)
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(filePath, base64Content, {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    });
    savedFiles.push(filePath);
    console.log(`Saved ${fileName} to ${filePath}`);
  }
  return savedFiles;
};

